# Why can I not populate an array in my back-end C# that I declare in my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in my VM and it works okay:

```
public ParamViewModel[] CardChoice { get; set; } = new[] 
    {
        new ParamViewModel { Id = 0, Name = CC.All.ShortText(), IsSelected = false, 
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF", TextColor="#999999", BorderColor="#999999" },
        new ParamViewModel { Id = 1, Name = CC.Catg.ShortText(), IsSelected = false, 
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF", TextColor="#999999" , BorderColor="#999999" },
    };
```

I changed it to this as I think I should not populate data in the VM but it seems not to work as expected:

VM

```
public ParamViewModel[] CardChoice { get; set; }
```

C# back-end

```
vm.CardChoice = new[] 
    {
        new ParamViewModel { Id = 0,  Name = CC.All.ShortText(),   IsSelected = false, 
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF", TextColor="#999999" , BorderColor="#999999" },
        new ParamViewModel { Id = 1,  Name = CC.Catg.ShortText(),  IsSelected = false, 
            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF", TextColor="#999999" , BorderColor="#999999" }
    };
```

But now nothing appears in the controls that use this data as back-end. Is there a problem with the way I am populating the data in the back-end?

Comment: If you're binding your array of ViewModels to a ListView your `ParamViewModel[]` should be an `ObservableCollection<ParamViewModel>`, which will then automatically update when you add to the Collection.

Comment: It's not bound to a list view I bind like this: <template:ButtonTemplate ButtonType="1" Grid.Column="0" Enabled="{Binding CardChoice[0].IsSelected}" Text="{Binding CardChoice[0].Name}" FrameBackgroundColor="{Binding CardChoice[0].BackgroundColor}" FrameBorderColor="{Binding CardChoice[0].BorderColor}" LabelTextColor="{Binding CardChoice[0].TextColor}" TapCommand="{Binding CardBtnCmd }" Param="{Binding CardChoice[0].Name}" />
                        <template:ButtonTemplate ButtonType="1" Grid.Column="1" Enabled="{Binding CardChoice[1].IsSelected}"

Comment: It still should be an `ObservableCollection` and I'd be careful about binding directly to an Item in an array like `CardChoice[0]`. It can lead to potential null reference exceptions or index out of range exceptions if not set at the correct time.

Comment: It does not have to be an OberservableCollection. If you want to monitor changes between the ViewModel and the View you have to make your ViewModel implement the `INotifyPropertyChanging`-Interface and call `OnPropertyChanged()` in your setters. Besides this, does "C# back-end" refer to the (c#-)backing-code of the xaml-file? If so, i believe your MVVM implementation is flawed. The cardchoice array should also be filled in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your VM code like below.

When you assing the property on a later stage than the UI is rendered then you have to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to tell the Renderer to rerender

```
public class YourVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ParamViewModel[] cardChoice;

    public ParamViewModel[] CardChoice
    {
        get { return cardChoice; }
        set 
        { 
            cardChoice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CardChoice")
        }
    }
}
```